# Can we use Microsoft Teams without SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams

As per [this](https://www.buckleyplanet.com/2022/05/can-you-use-microsoft-teams-without-sharepoint.html) blog we cannot use Microsoft Teams without the SharePoint. I understand the first part of the technical architecture of this for being why.

[image: Image Source: https://www.buckleyplanet.com/2022/05/can-you-use-microsoft-teams-without-sharepoint.html]

In the second diagram, it says - if you have OneDrive for business, we can use the Microsoft Teams as well. And as far as OneDrive for Business is concerned, it is meant for the individual user (for their personal uses). Then, if we don't have SharePoint license and having only the OneDrive for Business, then how the team member can collaborate through the teams channel? And where the teams channel files will be stored where each team member of the team can access the file (as this is OneDrive)?

Can someone please elaborate how Microsoft Teams works with the OneDrive for business for the team collaboration? Without SharePoint can we use the Microsoft Teams for the document management as well as for the team conversation?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to create a "team" or "channel" without using SharePoint. With OneDrive, you can use "chat/conversation" option with other users and shared files will be stored on OneDrive of user who sent the file.

Comment: I found a similar post for your reference:https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/microsoft-teams-without-sharepoint/m-p/2690489

Answer (score 1):

Teams as a desktop app (or web app) can be used to collaborate via chats, meetings and personal (OneDrive) sites.
So yes, you do not have to create a team with a SharePoint site behind to collaborate.